# how to display encrypted images in the view with Lockbox in ruby on rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

[Rails docs](https://apidock.com/rails/ActionController/Streaming/send_data) and [Lockbox docs](https://github.com/ankane/lockbox) say to do this in a controller if I want to stream data to the browser:

```
def license
 send_data user.image.front.read, :type => user.image.front.content_type, :disposition => 'inline'
end
```

This shows the file against a black background. But what if I have a bunch of files that I want to display in the view? One for each user?

```
def license
 @users = User.all
 #send_data wont work because i need to call it for each user displayed in the view
 #send_data user.image.front.read, :type => user.image.front.content_type, :disposition => 'inline'
end
```

I want to be able to do this in the view:

```
<% @users.each do |user| %>
 #display user.identity_document.front
<% end %>
```

I can't use `send_data` outside the controller, so is there another method I can use that would do what I need?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You'll want to use one action for the view and another to serve the images.

```
class UsersController < ApplicationController
  def index
    @users = User.all
  end

  def front_image
    user = User.find(params[:id])
    image = user.identity_document.front
    send_data image.read, type: image.content_type
  end
end
```

And in the index view:

```
<% @users.each do |user| %>
 <%= image_tag front_image_user_path(user) %>
<% end %>
```

(don't forget to hook up the routes as well)

Comment: This is what I ended up doing! Well, something like this anyway. Instead of displaying all encrypted images at once, I just made it so clicking a link would route to an action that displays that one picture. Figured it would be better to do that, than my og plan

Comment: From an auditing perspective, that sounds like a better approach. For instance, in the example above, it's a good practice to record the user that was viewed, the user who viewed it, their ip, the time, etc in the `front_image` method to track employee access to data.

Comment: Added an example of auditing to the readme as well: https://github.com/ankane/lockbox#auditing-master-experimental

Answer (score 1):

What do you mean by showing a bunch of PDF files in the view? Are you trying to show more than one PDF content as a single PDF by merging them? If that's the case then you have to merge all the PDF's content and stream the data to the browser.

For merging multiple PDF's you can make use of Ruby gem [combine_pdf](https://rubygems.org/gems/combine_pdf/versions/0.2.5)  or you can make use of python pyPDF2 to mege the PDF's separately.

Comment: they're encrypted jpgs

Comment: Then better way is to generate a PDF by attaching all the images in it and stream the PDF data to the browser.

Comment: thanks so much for helping! that seems like it would work, but it also seems like it might be too much? my users are uploading jpgs with CarrierWave, and the app encrypts them using Lockbox. then i - as admin - want to display all of the users and their associated jpg uploads in an admin panel. the Lockbox docs (https://github.com/ankane/lockbox) suggest using `send_data`, but that doesn't work for multiple records in a single view.